# How to disable Edge dev tools from automatically appearing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, edge-devtools

I was attempting to debug a deployed WebView2 application and followed some steps from Microsoft to use the Microsoft Edge dev tools to connect with it. I followed steps from these articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/remote-debugging?view=webview-1.0.864.33
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/debug-visual-studio-code?view=webview-1.0.864.33
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/main/GettingStartedGuides/WinForms_GettingStarted

I also installed Microsoft Edge Devtools Preview from the Microsoft Store.

Now I'm having a problem that the dev tools automatically appear when any WebView2 window is opened. (For example, when opening a message in Microsoft Outlook.)

I must have changed some setting to automatically open dev tools when a WebView2 viewer appears, but I have retraced my steps and I cannot find how to turn this off.

- I have uninstalled Microsoft Edge Devtools from the Microsoft Store
- I have turned off the developer feature and related settings in Windows settings
- I have removed any environment variables I set up for the webview2_additoinal_browser_arguments
- I have deleted any keys I added in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge

I'm hoping someone experienced with the Edge dev tools knows what I did and how to disable it.

Comment: Have you ever configured `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I had set an environment variable, but I have since removed it.

Comment: You can start by repairing/reinstalling WebView2 component and see how it works. Since Outlook standalone app also has this problem, it is not code-related I suppose.

Comment: I think after doing this a couple of times has helped; I haven't seen the dev tools pop up for a couple of days now! 